# VBA - Assigning values to certain elements of a class

Tags: xml, vba, class, properties, module

I have some XML with values I would like to assign through to a class, and I was wondering if it is possible to loop through certain elements of the class (as opposed to creating an array in the class).

So with reference to the XML snippet below, I'd like to have the class set up to pass values from the XML as follows:

```
event.homeTeamName
event.awayTeamName
event.homeSpread1 
event.homeSpread2
event.homeSpread3
event.homeSpread4
event.homeSpread5
event.totalPoints1
event.totalPoints2
event.totalPoints3
event.totalPoints4
event.totalPoints5
```

as opposed to

```
event.homeTeamName
event.awayTeamName
event.homeSpread(1) 
event.homeSpread(2)
event.homeSpread(3)
event.homeSpread(4)
event.homeSpread(5)
event.totalPoints(1)
event.totalPoints(2)
event.totalPoints(3)
event.totalPoints(4)
event.totalPoints(5)
```

Is there a way to loop through the *homeSpread1* - *homeSpread5* and *totalPoints1* - *totalPoints5* elements of the class when assigning the values from the XML?  I'm aware of the **Property Get** and **Property Let** features within the class module, but as far as I can see this would result in the undesired class involving arrays. Also as far as I can see I'd need to create a **Property Let/Get** for each array anyway.

Here is an example of the XML snippet:

```
                            <homeTeam type="Team1">
                                <name>Brisbane Roar</name>
                                <rotNum>2151</rotNum>
                            </homeTeam>
                            <awayTeam type="Team2">
                                <name>Adelaide United</name>
                                <rotNum>2152</rotNum>
                            </awayTeam>
                            <periods>
                                <period lineId="234921091">
                                    <spreads>
                                        <spread>
                                            <awaySpread>0.25</awaySpread>
                                            <awayPrice>2.01</awayPrice>
                                            <homeSpread>-0.25</homeSpread>
                                            <homePrice>1.909</homePrice>
                                        </spread>
                                        <spread altLineId="1893988627">
                                            <awaySpread>0.75</awaySpread>
                                            <awayPrice>1.549</awayPrice>
                                            <homeSpread>-0.75</homeSpread>
                                            <homePrice>2.59</homePrice>
                                        </spread>
                                        <spread altLineId="1893988629">
                                            <awaySpread>0.5</awaySpread>
                                            <awayPrice>1.751</awayPrice>
                                            <homeSpread>-0.5</homeSpread>
                                            <homePrice>2.21</homePrice>
                                        </spread>
                                        <spread altLineId="1893988631">
                                            <awaySpread>0</awaySpread>
                                            <awayPrice>2.47</awayPrice>
                                            <homeSpread>0</homeSpread>
                                            <homePrice>1.598</homePrice>
                                        </spread>
                                        <spread altLineId="1893988633">
                                            <awaySpread>-0.25</awaySpread>
                                            <awayPrice>2.91</awayPrice>
                                            <homeSpread>0.25</homeSpread>
                                            <homePrice>1.444</homePrice>
                                        </spread>
                                    </spreads>
                                    <totals>
                                        <total>
                                            <points>2.75</points>
                                            <overPrice>2.02</overPrice>
                                            <underPrice>1.884</underPrice>
                                        </total>
                                        <total altLineId="1893988628">
                                            <points>2.25</points>
                                            <overPrice>1.571</overPrice>
                                            <underPrice>2.49</underPrice>
                                        </total>
                                        <total altLineId="1893988630">
                                            <points>2.5</points>
                                            <overPrice>1.793</overPrice>
                                            <underPrice>2.12</underPrice>
                                        </total>
                                        <total altLineId="1893988632">
                                            <points>3</points>
                                            <overPrice>2.36</overPrice>
                                            <underPrice>1.632</underPrice>
                                        </total>
                                        <total altLineId="1893988634">
                                            <points>3.25</points>
                                            <overPrice>2.69</overPrice>
                                            <underPrice>1.49</underPrice>
                                        </total>
                                    </totals>
                                </period>
                            </periods>
```

Comment: If that's what you want to do then you can do that. It's not clear what's stopping you exactly?

Comment: That's my question - I want to know how to loop through certain elements of the class, where the elements aren't specifically an array

Comment: That's typically why this type of task would use an array: not doing so make your life much more difficult. The answer in your case though is probably to use `CallByName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim t As New clsTest
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 3
        CallByName t, "Total" & i, VbLet, i * 10
    Next i

    Debug.Print t.Total1, t.Total2, t.Total3 '--> 10, 20, 30

End Sub
```

clsTest:

```
Option Explicit

Private mT1 As Double
Private mT2 As Double
Private mT3 As Double

Property Let Total1(v As Double)
    mT1 = v
End Property
Property Get Total1() As Double
    Total1 = mT1
End Property
Property Let Total2(v As Double)
    mT2 = v
End Property
Property Get Total2() As Double
    Total2 = mT2
End Property
Property Let Total3(v As Double)
    mT3 = v
End Property
Property Get Total3() As Double
    Total3 = mT3
End Property
```

You can also simply use Public variables in `clsTest` (no need for getter/setter)

Comment: Many thanks, that's exactly what I was after.  I noticed when following the get/set method that the "v" array will create duplicate entries in that it creates both mT1/2/3 as well as Total1/2/3 but this should be easy enough to deal with.

Comment: mT1 etc are private variables used to back the public properties Total1 etc.  that's typically how you implement a property - there needs to be somewhere to store the value within the class...